# Why are my full calendar events disappearing when adding an eventRender?

Tags: jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I am new to Full Calendar. I downloaded all the latest files and made a test event and everything was working fine. However, when I added an eventRender to the code my event disappeared from the calendar.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2015-11-20',
            description: 'This is a cool event'
        }
        // more events here
    ],
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
            content: event.description
        });
    }
});
```

If I remove the eventRender the event returns to the calendar. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the console for errors? You may not be including the qtip/qtip2 js library and that will cause the events to error. Demos: [no qtip included](http://jsfiddle.net/zapnvzn6/) vs [has qtip lib](http://jsfiddle.net/zapnvzn6/1/)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2015-11-20',
            description: 'This is a cool event'
        }
        // more events here
    ],
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({ /* qtip is not included with fullcalendar */
            content: event.description
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I wish the instructions for fullcalendar had mentioned that you need a special library when they put this eventRender example on their website. (I tried to upvote your answer, but stackoverflow will not let me.) I take it qtip is not included in the regular JQuery library, so now I have to find that somewhere. Is there a list of eventRender functions that do work without adding a new library? Also, you asked if I checked the console for errors. Where is this console you are talking about located?

Comment: Yeah, the documentation/example doesn't indicate that qtip is an external dependency unfortunately. Anything from the standard jQuery library should be available to use (since fullcalendar uses jQuery it's a required include) http://qtip2.com for the qtip library. To access the javascript console (assuming Windows): Firefox = Tools->Web Developer->Web Console (Ctrl+Shift+K), Chrome = Menu->More Tools->Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I), Internet Explorer 10+, F12 should bring up developer tools, and click 'Console' tab.